# Angular ng serve with --configuration flag gets stuck generating browser application bundles

Tags: angular

When running just an ordinary ng serve everything works fine. But when I try to run ng serve with the --configuration flag it gets stuck on the "- Generating browser application bundles (phase: chunk asset optimization)..." step. This was working fine last week and nothing has since changed as far as I'm aware. attached is the terminal output.

[Terminal output]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT2DO.png

[configuration for serve]

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gxHh.png

Comment: Hi, could you please add the configurations part of you `angular.json` file (it's in the root directory of your project)

Comment: I just tried it with `ng s -c=staging` and it worked. (I'm using angular CLI 9.1.13)

Comment: @GrgKro It has been added

Comment: please check again that it's added :D I get the same image with both links.

Comment: My bad, should be working now.